# Formatting the text in the rich textbox

Tags: vb.net

How to make the selected text in a RichTextBox Bold,italic,underline ,change its color to red, Font to "Lucida Sans Unicode" and Text size to 18pt.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF RichTextBox: How to change selected text font?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496865/wpf-richtextbox-how-to-change-selected-text-font)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
this.richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font("Lucida Sans Unicode", 18, 
                                           FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Italic | FontStyle.Underline);
this.richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
```

I didn't tried it, here is VB.Net code

```
Me.richTextBox1.SelectionFont = New Font("Lucida Sans Unicode", 18, _
                                         FontStyle.Bold Or FontStyle.Italic Or FontStyle.Underline)
Me.richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red
```

Comment: "this" cannot be used........... Error 1 `Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'New' can be called without a narrowing conversion:
    'Public Sub New(familyName As String, emSize As Single, unit As System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit)': Argument matching parameter 'unit' narrows from 'String' to 'System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit'.
    'Public Sub New(familyName As String, emSize As Single, style As System.Drawing.FontStyle)': Argument matching parameter 'style' narrows from 'String' to 'System.Drawing.FontStyle'.`

Comment: Sorry I was using C# not VB.Net. I updated with VB.Net version.

Comment: The Selected text changed it font and color but the problem is that if I continue to type, the font and color of the new text also changes

Comment: Thats is the default behavior of RichTextBox, I am not sure you are able to resolve it.Try same with WordPad.

Answer (score 0):

**Font Bold**

```
Private Sub BoldToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BoldToolStripMenuItem.Click
        Try
        
   If Not RichTextBox1.SelectionFont Is Nothing Then

  RichTextBox1.SelectionFont = New Font(RichTextBox1.SelectionFont, RichTextBox1.SelectionFont.Style Xor FontStyle.Bold)

   End If

        Catch ex As Exception

            MsgBox(" Bold formatting is not possible", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Bold")

        End Try
    End Sub
```

***Font Italic***

```
   Private Sub ItalicToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ItalicToolStripMenuItem.Click
        Try
         If Not RichTextBox1.SelectionFont Is Nothing Then

  RichTextBox1.SelectionFont = New Font(RichTextBox1.SelectionFont, RichTextBox1.SelectionFont.Style Xor FontStyle.Italic)

         End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(" Italic formatting is not possible", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Italic")

        End Try
    End Sub
```

**Font Underline**

```
  Private Sub UnderlineToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles UnderlineToolStripMenuItem.Click
        Try
           If Not RichTextBox1.SelectionFont Is Nothing Then

  RichTextBox1.SelectionFont = New Font(RichTextBox1.SelectionFont, RichTextBox1.SelectionFont.Style Xor FontStyle.Underline)

          End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(" Underline formatting is not possible", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Underline")

        End Try
    End Sub
```

> Take a FontDialog and ColorDialog from Toolbox

**Font Color**

```
 Private Sub FontColorToolStripMenuItem1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FontColorToolStripMenuItem1.Click

        ColorDialog1.Color = RichTextBox1.ForeColor

        If ColorDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            RichTextBox1.SelectionColor = ColorDialog1.Color

        End If

    End Sub
```

**Font Face**

```
 Private Sub FontToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FontToolStripMenuItem.Click

        If Not RichTextBox1.SelectionFont Is Nothing Then
            FontDialog1.Font = RichTextBox1.SelectionFont
        Else
            FontDialog1.Font = Nothing
        End If

        FontDialog1.ShowApply = False
        FontDialog1.ShowEffects = True


        If FontDialog1.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            RichTextBox1.SelectionFont = FontDialog1.Font
        End If
    End Sub
```