# Vertically align tops of blocks of text in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, fonts, typography

I'm trying to visually `align` the top of the content of 2 (or more) blocks of `Text`.
The content and the `Font` (`Size`, `Family`, `Weight`) of each block can be modified by user.

I tried to play with the `GetCellAscent`, `GetCellDescent` and `GetLineSpacing` functions but the results depends only on the font and not the real content. And anyway I can't find how is distributed the difference between `LineSpacing` and `Ascent+ Descent` at the top and bottom of the block.

For example I want to produce this kind of output:

[image]

Any help?

Comment: Can't you just add a 'VerticalAlignment = "Top"' to the textblock element?

Comment: you should show us your code (xaml in this case): in these way it's simpler for us to help you

Comment: @Daniele Armanasco : This is pure code, no XAML to show.

Comment: @Deruijter : No, the VerticalAlignment align the surrounding rectangles, not the content (sorry, it was not clear in my first version).

Comment: Probably easier with RichText rather than TextBlock?

Comment: @Roger Rowland : I can't find any property of RichText that can be useful for my problem. Did I miss something ?

Comment: I'm thinking that if everything is in the same block, you don't have the same alignment issues. Does this post help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/3558237/2065121 - or maybe you need a custom control with a vertical StackPanel for the central part of your example?

Comment: @Roger Rowland: No, sorry, your post doesn't speak about vertical alignment, which is my real difficulty. And afaik RichText can't produce the output given in example.

Comment: Why not draw these as geometries on a canvas if you need precise layout control?

Comment: @Richard : I can do that, but it never helps me to know the height of the output text.

Answer (score 1):

Try This.....

```
   <Grid Width="171" Height="100" Background="Black" Margin="257,78,75,133">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />

        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Name="aaa" Text="12" FontSize="40" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1"   FontWeight="Bold"   Foreground="White" />
        <TextBlock Text="$" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="20" Grid.Column="1" FontFamily="Euphemia" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" Margin="8,0,72,0" />
        <TextBlock Text="00 le Kg" FontSize="15" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" FontFamily="Euphemia" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White"/>

    </Grid>
```

Comment: I was probably not clear enough but my problem is to align the top of the "12" block with the top of the "$" (or "€" or whatever) block. And this for any font family/size/weight...

Comment: see the edited version and change the Fontsize of textblock aaa to see the changes... is it ri8 now????

Comment: (Sorry to answer so late, I did not receive notification of the change) I know it's possible to manually align the two textblock content. But I want to do it automatically.