# Problems with RichTextBox.Selection and TextSelection.ApplyPropertyValue

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I'm trying to create a text editor in WPF using a RichTextBox.
My problem is with changing the font size of my text. My code works as intended in every case, except when the cursor is inside a word. In this case it should not change the font size of anything, except the font size of the text to come if the user writes anything. The problem is that for some reason `TextSelection.ApplyPropertyValue(RichTextBox.FontSizeProperty, value)` changes the font size of the whole word when the cursor is inside a word.

This is my eventHandler:

```
private void fontSizeBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox)sender;
    string value = (string)comboBox.SelectedValue;

    if (comboBox.IsDropDownOpen)
    {
        TextSelection text = textBoxMain.Selection;
        richTextBox.Focus();
        text.ApplyPropertyValue(RichTextBox.FontSizeProperty, value);
    }            
}
```

And I cannot use something like adding `!text.Text.IsEmpty` inside the if statement, because I still need to be able to change the font size for text to be written.

I have found similar questions on StackOverFlow, but none with an actual working answer.

Edit: Added XAML

```
<Window x:Class="MathEdit.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MathEdit"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="Open" Executed="OpenCommandBinding_Executed"></CommandBinding>
    <CommandBinding Command="Save" Executed="SaveCommandBinding_Executed"></CommandBinding>
    <CommandBinding Command="SaveAs" Executed="SaveAsCommandBinding_Executed"></CommandBinding>
</Window.CommandBindings>

<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="O" Modifiers="Control" Command="Open"></KeyBinding>
    <KeyBinding Key="S" Modifiers="Control" Command="Save"></KeyBinding>
    <KeyBinding Key="S" Modifiers="Control+Alt" Command="SaveAs"></KeyBinding>
</Window.InputBindings>

<DockPanel>
    <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <MenuItem Header="_File">
            <MenuItem Header="_New" InputGestureText="Ctrl+N" />
            <MenuItem Header="_Open" InputGestureText="Ctrl+O" Command="Open"/>
            <MenuItem Header="_Save" InputGestureText="Ctrl+S" Command="Save"/>
            <MenuItem Header="_Save As" InputGestureText="Ctrl+Alt+S" Command="SaveAs"/>
            <Separator />
            <MenuItem Header="_Exit" InputGestureText="Alt+F4" />
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="_Tools">
            <MenuItem Header="_Check if toby = on" IsCheckable="false" IsChecked="True" Click="MenuItem_Click" />
            <MenuItem Header="_Settings" Click="MenuItem_Click_2" IsCheckable="True" />
            <MenuItem Header="_Add formula" x:Name="menuItemAdd" Click="MenuItem_Add_Click" />
        </MenuItem>
        <ComboBox x:Name="fontSizeBox" Width="40" SelectedValuePath="Content" SelectionChanged="fontSizeBox_SelectionChanged" SelectedIndex="2">
            <ComboBoxItem Content="5"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="12"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="16"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="20"/>
        </ComboBox>
    </Menu>
    <Grid x:Name="gridParent">
    <RichTextBox x:Name="richTextBox" AcceptsReturn="True" SelectionChanged="textBoxMain_SelectionChanged" />
    </Grid>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: Is there a chance you can post the XAML also?

Comment: Here is your answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/4199012/169714 you are applying the fontsize to the selection, but when the cursor is in a word. there is no selection, so you have to apply it to the upcoming text.

Comment: As also pointed out by the comment to that answer, it does not work.

Comment: So, you want the ComboBox to do what? Change the font of the word that is selected, or the text that is going to be written? Or both?

Comment: I wanted to be able to have the cursor inside a word, change the font size on the comboBox (but not change the font size of the word) and then if any text input would come from the user, he would be able to write in the newly chosen font size. I realize my code right now actually works similar to how it works in Word and should probably take Jürgens advice and revise my requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simple application of a property value to a no-text selection is not possible. Look at what you get when you apply it to a real selection: Say you have a text "hello brave new world". The document inside the RTB looks like this (simplified)

```html
<FlowDocument>
  <Paragraph>
    <Run>hello brave new world</Run>
  </Paragraph>
</FlowDocument>
```

When you select "brave" and change the font size (or anything else), the document changes to

```html
<FlowDocument>
  <Paragraph>
    <Run>hello </Run>
    <Run FontSize="20">brave</Run>
    <Run> new world</Run>
  </Paragraph>
</FlowDocument>
```

An attribute has to be applied to some text; there is no way to change "nothing", as you requested. If you want to achieve what to me looks closest to your requirement, you will have to split the document yourself - when the selection is empty - and create an empty run with the desired font size. So the above example would look like this (assuming, the caret is positioned before "brave"):

```html
<FlowDocument>
  <Paragraph>
    <Run>hello </Run>
    <Run FontSize="20"></Run>
    <Run>brave new world</Run>
  </Paragraph>
</FlowDocument>
```

As this leaves endless possibilities to end up with an infinite number of "empty" Runs, I would advise to revise your requirement.

Comment: I'm gonna revise my requirement as you suggested.